# PHP echo MySQL entries until screen is filled

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm using this code.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo "" . $row['car'] . "";
  }
```

to display data from a database with a few thousand entries. I'm updating this page with ajax to refresh the data as new db entries are coming in.

How would I mend this so that the while loop is broken once the entire screen is filled with entries? Right now I get 5000 entries printed in the browser. Sure I could limit it with MySQL "LIMIT 0,30" but then a big screen would still only get half filled while a smaller mobile screen get filled with too many.

What I want is something like "While screen not filled, echo ".row., if screen filled 90% stop echo" I don't want any scrolling or overflow on my page, I just want the echo to continue until the screen is filled.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from PHP, PHP is server side, you can't control from server if the page is filled at 90%.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to save the screen height as a session with Javascript? And then calculate the amount of rows needed to echo. Keep in mind this page is updating every 5 sec, not just once.

Answer (score 0):

You should use responsive design concept, which means that 20 or 30 outputs will fill the screen, or any number you would like (Check out bootstrap grid system). It's more difficult to echo different kind of output according to the screen size and with PHP it's impossible to do. You will need good knowledge of JavaScript at least.